# File uploads with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

We are using CefSharp (v37.0.0 NuGet package) in a C# WinForms application. We are looking for a way to (programmatically) trigger file upload actions. How, if at all, can that be done?
A couple of additional thoughts:

- We have a file upload dialog on a page where, normally, a user would select a file. This works fine, we intercept the dialog call via IDialogHandler and provide the file.
- Now we want to trigger the same dialog and pre-set the file. While the dialog opens successfully from an "ExecuteScriptAsync" call, we are unable to pre-select the file. Possibly due to the following reason: [how to create/initialize the file object using file path html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933565/how-to-create-initialize-the-file-object-using-file-path-html5)
- Our next idea was to have the dialog open normally and issue a click event programmatically so the browser would open the file dialog (which we would then catch via IDialogHandler and provide the file we desire).
- Trying this approach, our observation is as follows:
- Following a user action (e.g. button click inside the browser), we can programmatically "click" the file input button.
- Doing the same from a call originating via ExecuteScriptAsync, the dialog (or call in IDialogHandler) does not come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doing the same from a call originating via ExecuteScriptAsync, the dialog (or call in IDialogHandler) does not come up.

This is probably due to the same security restrictions that apply to normal JavaScript: [Programmatically open upload file dialog in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161638/programmatically-open-upload-file-dialog-in-chrome)

I think you will need to:

1. In JavaScript:

   1. Scroll the file upload button into view, `Element.scrollIntoView()`
   2. Calculate the co-ordinates of the file upload button, `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`
   3. Return the co-ordinates to C#.
2. In C#:

   1. Programmatically send a mouse click to the co-ordinates (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094398/how-to-programatically-mouse-move-click-right-click-and-keypress-etc-in-winfor))

Comment: That's definitely an obvious way to do it - thanks for pointing that out Yoshi! We have solved it in a slightly different way now. We let the user click our final "Save" button on the html form. But in this special case we open the "file open" dialog - which works because it originated from a user action -, which we then catch from C# and set the file appropriately. Next, we call the save function again right from the same C# event handler, which will finally run the save/upload logic. Cool stuff this tight interaction between javascript/.NET.

Answer (score 4):

The file `TempFileDialogHandler` on the CefSharp sample project has an example of this.

```
    public class TempFileDialogHandler : IDialogHandler
    {
        public bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefFileDialogMode mode, string title, string defaultFilePath, List<string> acceptFilters, int selectedAcceptFilter, IFileDialogCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Continue(selectedAcceptFilter, new List<string> { Path.GetRandomFileName() });

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Replace `Path.GetRandomFileName()` for your filepath and then attach the handler to the browser like this:

```
browser.DialogHandler = new TempFileDialogHandler();
```

Answer (score -2):

I might be wrong but this also can be achieve by using jquery file uploader plugins rather than doing it yourself.

Ajax Upload
Uploadify