# can i place an input file tag inside a button?

Tags: css, forms, input

Im currently working on having a button to upload a file, but i dont want to use the default input[type=file]

here's my snippet:

```
%button.btn
   Upload your own
   %input{ :type => "file", :class => 'file-input' }
```

and here's the css:

```
left: -34; // to align it with the button
top: -23;
position: relative;
opacity: 0;
```

currently it works, im just not sure about the markup. twitter has the same structure also when trying to upload a profile photo.

Comment: _but i dont want to use the default input[type=file]_ **Any reason??**

Comment: validate it on the w3c

Comment: What precise HTML are you trying to end up with?

Comment: a simple button that would open a file upload window when clicked, not the default input[type=file], which im trying to hide. Currently this is working, im just trying to find out if it is a valid markup

Comment: Check this link, this has best answers for your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input

Answer (score 2):

Set the opacity of the input file button to 0 and position it over the styled button div.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm doing, im just trying to find out if this is a valid markup

Comment: It is, another method would be to have your input file button positioned absolutely and out of sight and then through javascript when your fake button is pressed you click your input file button, both work as intended. @HarveyKatrina

Comment: i just found it that it's an invalid markup, but can i still get away with this one?

Comment: hmm can you show me the source ? I v been using such techniques for a while, but instead of actual <button> it's a <div> styled as a custom button @HarveyKatrina

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use:

```
<button type='file'>Content</button>
```

It works the same.

Comment: [It really doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/U9cjM/), in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
```

more details [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)