# How to choose and upload a local image file from the file dialog via Javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

Can I somehow choose and upload a local image file from the file dialog via Javascript (I'm trying to use UserScript to do it)?

I can open the file dialog via the following code:

```
function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents")
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false)
   node.dispatchEvent(evt)
}

performClick(document.getElementById('fld_images'))
```

But what about uploading? Is it possible? Maybe HTML5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you could convert your image file to a data url, and use that to fill in the file input's value with JS.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for anyone that wants to help http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/965/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **file input**, then once you have the file handle you can use the fileReader to access the file. JavaScript cannot directly select files from the user's drive due to security.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />


$('#fileInput').on('change', function() {
    alert(this.files)
})
```

`this.file[0]` will be your first file.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Dealing_with_binary_data

Comment: You can only get the file handle from the change event. The change event will only fire if the user clicks on the fields. The question is about triggering the click event http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/965/

Answer (score 1):

If your file field is visible, your code should work. It probably doesn't work because you've made your file field invisible. Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/56449/adardesign with the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302101/227299

Try setting the upload field to be `position:absolute; top:-100px` http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/967/

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="fld_images">
<button id="button">Upload</button>
```

**JS**

```
function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt, true);
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    performClick(document.getElementById('fld_images'));
});
```

**CSS**

```
#fld_images{ position:absolute; top:-100px; }
```