# Safari input='file' doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, file, input, safari

I have div which one on click trigger input-file.
In other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) it's working but in Safari(5.1.7) it doesn't.
Any idea why?

```
 $(function() {
 $("#mask-button-file").click(function () {
    $("#mask-load-file").trigger('click');
    });
});


<div id="mask-button-file" class="hover active">
        . . .
</div>
<input type="file" id="mask-load-file" name="file1" >

#mask-load-file{
display:none;
opacity:0;
}
#mask-button-file{
width:81px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #f70808;
float:left;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px;
margin-left:1px;
cursor:pointer;
}
#mask-button-file:active{
background-color:#DF0005;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the input is being set to `display:none` and this has issue in safari.
Instead of hiding it, wrap it inside a div with `height`, `width` set to zero.

```
<div>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="upload"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Another option will be to position the input out of the viewport so that it's not visible.

You can refer this post: [Jquery trigger file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)  for more options about it.