# trigger click on input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this mark up

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <a href="#" id="capture">Submit Cleanup</a>
</div>
```

and jQuery as follow

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#capture').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#file').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

the script works as expected on PC browser, but when i try on mobile device the camera doesnt prompt. also i already tried using `click()`, but same result.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried  `$('#file')[0].trigger('click');`?

Comment: @Satpal yes, already tried that as well, still not working.
Anton could it be the problem comes from the phone it self? :|

Comment: Works fine on my android v4.4.2 http://jsfiddle.net/qd2r01er/ What phone are you trying on?

Comment: $('#file').trigger('click');

Comment: @JqueryKing please see my current code..

Comment: TL;DR: `<input type="file">` `click()` seems to only work from an `<a>`, not from an `<input type="button">`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a security feature. Some browsers don't allow a non-manual click on file inputs. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Style-Guide#why-isnt-it-possible-to-programmatically-trigger-the-file-input-selection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input).

**Why isn't it possible to programmatically trigger the file input selection?**

> Most browsers prevent submitting files when the input field didn't
> receive a direct click (or keyboard) event as a security precaution.
> Some browsers (e.g. Google Chrome) simply prevent the click event,
> while e.g. Internet Explorer doesn't submit any files that have been
> selected by a programmatically triggered file input field. Firefox 4
> (and later) is so far the only browser with full support for invoking
> "click"-Events on a completely hidden (display: none) file input
> field.

Comment: thanks for the question. i'll make changes as explained

Answer (score 10):

In most browsers(

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('#capture').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#file')[0].click();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <a href="#" id="capture">Submit Cleanup</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```html
<label>
<input type="file" name="myfile" accept="application/pdf" id="myfile" style="display:none">
CLICK HERE!
</label>
<br>
<a href="javascript:document.querySelector('input#myfile').click()">OR HERE</a>
```