# $('element').click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my file input element:

`<input type="file" id="StudentPhoto" value="StudentPhoto" style="display: none;">`

This is the validation function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StudentPhoto').change(function()
    {
        var file_data = $("#StudentPhoto").prop("files")[0];
        var size = file_data.size;
        var type = file_data.type;
        var name = file_data.name;
        var input = $("#StudentPhoto");

        if(type !== 'image/png' && type !== 'image/jpg' && type !== 'image/jpeg')
        {
            alert("Only JPG & PNG files are allowed to upload as student photo.");
            $('#StudentPhoto').click();
        }
        else if(size > 2097152)
        {
            alert("The maximum photo size is 2MB\n");
            $('#StudentPhoto').click();
        }
    });
});
```

If the file chosen by the user has an invalid format or size, it's supposed to pop up the dialog to ask him to choose the file again, but it doesn't, the statement `$('#StudentPhoto').click();` in the function doesn't work. Why? Is there any other method?

Comment: its a file input, so click event for this for sure is show the window and let user choose the file

Comment: It doesn't work neither @ArunPJohny

Comment: sorry... I really mean `doesn't`... missed that

Comment: You should use `accept` attribute in `<input type="file">` instead of checking in JS.

Comment: Not a real workaround, but you can limit the file types by setting `accept='.jpg | .jpeg | .png'` attribute. File size restriction can probably be done when you submit your form rather than click on <kbd>open</kbd> button of the file dialog...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the `.trigger()` method to make the click event fire on the button. We'll also use `input` since you stored the file field already.

```
input.trigger('click');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't work from a change handler of the same element - at least in chrome

Comment: what is the difference between `$('#StudentPhoto').click();` and `input.trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML DOM click() method:

```
document.getElementById('StudentPhoto').click();
```

Comment: I found this answer. It may help you understand your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25886585/3861639

Comment: @shess But `.click()` function for my file input works in other function/condition.

Comment: this answer is not related. If jQuery works in other case, this traditional JS click is the same as jQuery version's `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file input element to:

`<input type="file" id="StudentPhoto" value="StudentPhoto" style="visibility: hidden">`

Note that I used `visibility: hidden`, instead of `display: none`.

You **cannot** call the click event on a non-displayed file input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inside the change function and want to click on the same selector, you can use the this.click()

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StudentPhoto').change(function()
    {
        var file_data = $("#StudentPhoto").prop("files")[0];
        var size = file_data.size;
        var type = file_data.type;
        var name = file_data.name;
        var input = $("#StudentPhoto");

        if(type !== 'image/png' && type !== 'image/jpg' && type !== 'image/jpeg')
        {
            alert("Only JPG & PNG files are allowed to upload as student photo.");
            this.click();
        }
        else if(size > 2097152)
        {
            alert("The maximum photo size is 2MB\n");
            this.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to insert your callback withing the click event:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#StudentPhoto').change(function()
            { 
                var file_data = $("#StudentPhoto").prop("files")[0];
                var size = file_data.size;
                var type = file_data.type;
                var name = file_data.name;
                var input = $("#StudentPhoto");

                if(type !== 'image/png' && type !== 'image/jpg' && type !== 'image/jpeg')
                {
                    alert("Only JPG & PNG files are allowed to upload as student photo.");
                    $('#StudentPhoto').click();
                }
                else if(size > 2097152)
                {

                    $('#StudentPhoto').click(function(){
alert("The maximum photo size is 2MB\n");
});
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: you misunderstood my question

Comment: Hi Ah Yong, can you be more specific with your question?