# File element cant trigger after get it from ajax

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a form upload file from computer.
My step to upload

1, Click to button

2, After click will run ajax to load the field from server.

3, After loaded that field, I append it to own form. And trigger click it hope a window upload will show. But it does not work. I using jquery 2.1.0

```
$('.form-file').click();
```

It already and show by console.log

Comment: This is duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div id="upload">Upload</div>
  <div id="file_wrapper"></div>
</form>
```

form.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#upload').click(function(){
    $('#file_wrapper').load('/element.html', function(){
      $('#file').trigger('click');
    });
  });
})
```

element.html

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
```