# JQuery .click() function not working inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following form with a file input which needs to be activated depending on the result of an Ajax Call.

```
<form id="checkin_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="checkinfile"><br>
</form>
```

The javascript function which will trigger the click funtion is:

```
function clickCheckInFile() 
{
    var file_index = selected_file.id;
    var file_name = $(selected_file).children('td:nth(1)').text();

    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/check_file.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {file_index: file_index, file_name: file_name},
        success: function(data){
        if (data['response'] == 200)
        {
            if (data['type'] != "dir")
            {
                if (data['checked_out'] == 1 || data['checked_out'] == "1")
                {
                    if (data['checked_out_by'] == username)
                    {
                        if (data['user_permissions'][1] == 1)
                        {
                            $('#checkinfile').click(); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('Access Denied.');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('Access Denied');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('File is not checked out.');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Cannot check out a folder');
            }
        }
        else if (data['response'] == 300)
        {
            alert(data['message']);
        }
        else
        {
            handleAjaxResponse(data['response']);
        }
    }});
}
```

The line not working is the $('#checkinfile').click(); portion. I can put an alert message that triggers in that spot so the code is calling that line. When I move the click to prior to the ajax call it works fine.

Comment: It is executing, but there's nothing to handle `$('#checkinfile').click()`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/210643/1133144) may be relevant

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're trying to force a click event. the .click() says what to do when it's clicked - it doesn't trigger a click.

Use .trigger() for that:

```
$('#checkinfile').trigger('click');
```

Then you need to separately add what to do when it's clicked like this:

```
 $('#checkinfile').click(function(){
//do things here
});
```

As for the **issue with the file browser**. Try this solution [from this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302101/1543447):

Position the input as `position:absolute` and `top:*number that will remove it from viewport*` and it'll work

[Here's the docs for .trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: what will `click` execute when triggered ? No function specified.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Funny you should ask - I just updated my answer to include that.

Comment: The worked, how would I trigger the file input to open the file browser then?

Comment: Change the name to `file` and it should work. BTW - can you mark the answer as I did answer the question :-)

Comment: The action of clicking works and I am able to alert a message but it did not solve my problem. I need the file input to open the file browser upon click.

Comment: Just updated my response to include a solution to that, too. You just need to set it outside the viewport with an `position:absolute` and `top`

Answer (score 2):

Though it's generally preferred to [use `.trigger()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) when triggering an event (if for no other reason than clarity), this line of code seems to work fine:

```
$('#checkinfile').click();
```

(assuming that the selector finds the element(s) you expect, of course)

However, the real question is... What do you expect this element to *do* when the click event is triggered?  According to the code posted, there is no event handler for that.

It's a file input, so maybe you expect it to open the file dialog for the user?  While it's possible that some browsers *may* do that, I suspect it's not standard or expected behavior.  The file input is notorious for things like this (events, styling, etc.) and can be a bit of a pain at times.

What I *suspect* is happening is that the browser, potentially for security reasons, is *requiring* actual user interaction before invoking the file dialog.  Again, this behavior *may* be browser specific, but take a look at a couple of examples here:

- [Unable to invoke file dialog automatically](http://jsfiddle.net/961djsrq/)
- [Able to invoke file dialog from code after manual button click](http://jsfiddle.net/961djsrq/1/)
- [Unable to invoke file dialog, using manual button with automatic click](http://jsfiddle.net/961djsrq/3/)

The pattern seems to be that manual interaction is required to open the file dialog, even if it's opened from code.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to trigger the file input to open its file dialog. When I overwrote the default click event, I was able to alert a message. Anytime I used #(checkinfile).click() it would not work even when I added a button to be clicked programmatically first.

Comment: @user2448760: That's exactly my point.  The browser seems to prevent that from happening without a manual user interaction event.  The code is "working" just fine, it's simply trying to do something the browser doesn't allow.

Comment: But outside of the Ajax call the #(checkinfile).click() works perfectly fine. Why would executing after an Ajax success be different?

Comment: @user2448760: Does it work perfectly fine?  In my browser (Firefox) it doesn't (see my first jsFiddle example).

Comment: In both Firefox and Chrome if I move the #(checkinfile).click() outside the ajax portion of code but still within the function it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @user2448760: And what invokes that function?  Would it happen to be an event from manual user interaction?  In that case take a look at my second jsFiddle example.  When invoked from manual user interaction it works fine.  An AJAX callback, however, isn't user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#checkinfile').click();
});

$(document).on('change', '#checkinfile', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="checkin_form" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="checkinfile">
</form>
<button id="clickme">click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its easy

```
$( "example" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( "click" );
});
```

You can see documentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope it helps you

Comment: The OP is trying to *trigger* a click event.  How will binding an event handler accomplish that?