# jQuery drop and trigger input type file

Tags: jquery, html, input, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a custom drag drop and file upload. My div container is empty. Upon drop file i am '' an '' type file into the container and want to trigger its file attachment functionality. my code is not working properly . kindly advice or guide. your favour will be appreciated.

following is my code

```
<div class="drag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

function allowDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    function addinputfile(){
        $('.drag').append('<div class="upload"><input type="file" name="ufile[]" id="ufile" multiple></div>');
    }

    function drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('something dropped here!');
        addinputfile();
        $('#input#ufile').trigger("click");
    }
```

code is simply adding '' file type and hitting it to use for file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, some browsers won't allow event trigger on the input: file, Click event will work only, when it comes directly from the user.

But alternative is there to do this, refer it here [Jquery trigger file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)