# How to trigger element click on angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input file and it is hidden. I want to trigger the input file once the button is clicked but my code is not working. What changes does it need to make it work?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="data.file" id="upload" style="display:none;">
<button type="button" ng-click="browseFile()">Choose a file</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.browseFile = function () {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#upload')).triggerHandler('click'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In html use something like below

```
<img id="preview_image" src="" accept="image/*" class="upload_img" alt="">

<input id="image_upload" ng-model="file" type="file" class="upload_image_file" />
```

And in controller use `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch("file", function() {
  readURL(angular.element("#image_upload")[0]);
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input && input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      angular.element("#preview_image").attr("src", e.target.result);
      vm.base64File = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

For more info, read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/)

---

**Update**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.file = '';

  $scope.$watch("file", function() {
    console.log($scope.file)
  });
});
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label class="upload_image_label" for="image_upload">
      choose file
      <input id="image_upload" file-model="file" type="file" style="display:none" />
    </label>

    <hr> <br> File: {{file}}

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its not what i meant. I'm not uploading or reading the file yet. i want to browse input file through custom button.

Comment: Try it now! @Rye

Answer (score 0):

As adardesign said

> This is due to a security restriction.
>   I found out that the security restriction is only when the

```
<input type="file"/>
```

> is set to display:none; or is visibility:hidden. 
>   So i tried positioning it outside the viewport by setting
>   position:absolute and top:-100px; and voilà it works.

You can find more in this post: [Jquery trigger file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)

Comment: Its not what i meant.

Comment: It does not work probably beacause it's hidden due to a security restriction. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input

Comment: so you mean. its not possible on angular js. its only work on jquery?