# How do I open the file upload dialog box on hover of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

How do I open a file dialog box on hover of an upload button using jQuery of JavaScript?

When I do the same thing with on click of the upload button it's working.

I want do this think on React. Is there is any npm package for React?

This is the code I am trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="upload"/>
        <input type="button" id="Uplad_button" name="upload_file" value="upload" />

    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Uplad_button').hover(function(){
        console.log("hover")
        $('#upload').click();
      });
      $('#Uplad_button').click(function(){
        console.log("click")
        $('#upload').click();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is How to open.

Comment: I think there is no way to achieve this except when your element is hidden (visibility or display).  This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302101/259889

Comment: @Sid It' working with click event but not working on hover action. This is my client requiremnt.

Comment: Exactly, the link that I have posted above has a hacky solution.  The reason why it is not allowed is Security.

Comment: Then there is no way to do this?

Comment: From what I have read online, I don't think so.

Comment: Is this valid HTML (stuff outside of tag `html`)?