# html, javascript file upload dialog under submenu

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, openfiledialog

in the submenu, when you click "Load CSV file", I want to get file type upload dialog.

here is my code but it does not open any file upload dialog.

...

```
<div class="subnav-content">
  <input type="file" id = "csvfile" style="display:none;" accept=".csv"/>
    <a href="#" id="loadCSV" onclick="chooseCSV()">Load CSV file</a>
    <a href="#" id="login">Login to DB</a>
    <a href="#" id="logout">Logout DB</a>
    <a href="#" id="exit">Exit</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
function chooseCSV(){
    $("#csvfile").click();
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem, your code works fine for me. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: these guys already discussed your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input