# I can't make a file dialog pop up

Tags: javascript, godot

This is my code. I am running it in godot with JavaScript.eval() is it a problem with my code or the game engine?

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.id = "fileImporter";
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.click();
```

Comment: The code works perfectly fine when loaded through a web browser, I suggest it is something to do with running it with a game engine as you suggested.

Comment: It could be a security restriction.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)

Comment: works fine here

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you are planning to support, you could consider using the [`showOpenFilePicker` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker#browser_compatibility).

Example: https://rightful-serious-cost.glitch.me/

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Open file</button>
```

```js
async function handleOpenFile() {
  const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
    types: [
      {
        description: 'JSON document',
        accept: {
          'text/*': ['.json'],
        },
      },
    ],
    multiple: false,
  });
  const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
  const contents = await file.text();

  console.log(contents);
  document.querySelector('textarea').textContent = contents;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => handleOpenFile());
```

Source code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/rightful-serious-cost?path=index.html%3A13%3A6